# Excel: Position text box via macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I got a Command Button in my Excel file, which adds a new text box at a specific location. Now i got a problem. I'd like to add the text box automatically under the previous one. So like on my screenshot. I created "Testeintrag" manually and "Titelname hier eingeben" gets created when I hit the + on the top. I placed the box manually with

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationUpward, 932, 270, 27, _
    150).Select
```

But when I add another one, it just over my previous one, but I'd like that it creates the next one under my previous one, and so on. How can I do this?

[image: The Text box "Titelname hier eingeben" gets created when I hit the + on the top.]

Thats my whole macro:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationUpward, 932, 270, 27, _
    150).Select
Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
    "Titelname hier eingeben"
End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need a way to find the position of the last textbox. If these are the only shapes that should be easy enough. Then specify the position of the new box based on the position of the last box.

Comment: Yes, these are the only shapes. How do I find the position of the last box? Sorry, I am not really into Visual Basic

Comment: You could store the postion of the last box directly on the sheet in a range or on another worksheet that you then have VeryHidden

Comment: Yes, I could, but _how_ do I store that and return it in my macro afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit2:** Updated code according to new requirement.

```
Option Explicit

Sub addayetnothertextbox()

    Dim mybox

    Dim top, left, height, width, margin
    margin = 20

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes

        left = .Item(.Count).left
        top = .Item(.Count).top + .Item(.Count - 1).height + margin
        width = .Item(.Count).width
        height = .Item(.Count).height

        Set mybox = .addtextbox(msoTextOrientationUpward, left, top, width, height)

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That wont work for me. It still adds the text box to the position 932, 270 and when I add another one, its still just overlapping...

Comment: Yes thats true, I have much to learn :) But I dont need VBA in my profession and never used it before.
So actually I have to do `Box2.Top = Box1.Top + Box1.Height + 20` for every single box? So `Box3.Top = Box2.Top + Box2.Height + 20` , `Box4.Top = Box3.Top + Box3.Height + 20` , ... `Box180.Top = Box179.Top + Box179.Height + 20` and so on? Pretty elaborate isnt it...

Comment: Well I only got **2 shapes** but the goal is that I can add as many boxes as I like and every box is automatically under the previous one. So up to like 52 boxes (for every week of the year)

Comment: edited. i trust the initial information is still valid and textboxes are the only shapes in the sheet.

Comment: Thanks ! That's working. Sorry that you missunderstood me sometimes, but my english isn't simply the best :) Thanks for your effort and patience tho

Comment: that's np, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Since that method was to complicated for me, I created a simple alternative.

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Left As Double, Top As Double
With ActiveSheet
Left = ActiveCell.Left
Top = ActiveCell.Top
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationUpward, Left, Top, 27, _
    190).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
    "Titelname hier eingeben"
End With
End Sub
```

So I have to select a cell and then hit that "Add"-Button. Then it adds a text box with the size 190x25 at the location where the active cell is.

Comment: Whilst this may work, its not particularly user friendly, and the options suggested by Martin Dreher are far better.